# How to execute an unknown amount of function calls/"pipes" based upon data stored within a tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, metaprogramming, rlang

I'll try to make this example as reproducible and explicit as possible.

To **fully** reproduce the code you'll need the following packages...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
```

And, you'll need to create the following "dummy" set of data...

```
dummy_data <-
  tibble(
    category = c("A01", "A01", "A01", "A01", "A05", "A05", "A05", "A15", "A15", "A15", "A15"),
    unknown = c("w", "b", "c", "l", "w", "b", "c", "w", "b", "c", "o"),
    known = c(388610, 7760, 94970, 129931, 366472, 360477, 82212, 128021, 114379, 72185, 32807),
    known_sum = c(1470189, 1470189, 1470189, 1470189, 1110194, 1110194, 1110194, 831287, 831287, 831287, 831287)
  )
```

My goal is use the OMPR package (mixed linear programming) to back-solve for a set of unknown factors based on an equation and some bounds/constraints which depend on data stored in the "dummy_data" tibble. I managed to quickly use the OMPR package to get the following example working through "manually inputting" all the necessary information from the dummy data. Below is the example for **only** the first category (A01)...

```
model <-
  MILPModel() %>%
    add_variable(w, lb = 1.8, ub = 2.8, type = "continuous") %>%
    add_variable(b, lb = 2.0, ub = 3.0, type = "continuous") %>%
    add_variable(c, lb = 1.1, ub = 1.8, type = "continuous") %>%
    add_variable(l, lb = 1.3, ub = 1.7, type = "continuous") %>%
    set_objective(388610*w+ 7760*b+ 94970*c+ 129931*l, "min") %>%
    add_constraint((388610*w+ 7760*b+ 94970*c+ 129931*l) == 1470189) %>%
    solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))
```

Now, the goal is to create an identical model for each "category" (i.e. A05, A15, and any other potential Axx), not just A01 as shown above. I could easily create 'model2' and 'model3' then manually input all the numbers. Removing the "l" variable for A05, and then adding a new "o" variable in for A15 (with its own specific bounds).

However, this doesn't feel tidy, it's a lot of manual work, and it quickly becomes increasingly unsustainable as the number of categories/variables increases.

**Is there a tidy-way to step through the dummy data set (perhaps using a group_map on "category") where the mapping function creates a distinct model (as manually demonstrated above) but for every category - basing the model parameters on the unique set of variables/numbers present within the dataset for each category?**

- Creating only the variables shown for that category (i.e. w, b, c, l for A01; w, b, c for A05; w, b, c, o for A15)
- Attribute the correct "known" numbers within the set_objective and add_constraint calls.
- Attribute the correct "known_sum" number to the end (RHS) of the add_constraint call.

I've tagged this question with rlang/metaprogramming because it feels  to me that I'm moving towards "creating code using code" to solve this problem (using quo, eval, etc.). However, I am completely naïve/inexperienced in that part of R-programming, and I'm bullish that there might be a much simpler way to solve this problem using a less-manual (and more-tidy) methodology!

Appreciate any thought/assistance you might thrown my way in advance!

Cheers,
Troy